# 500 internal server error, how to debug

Tags: php, debugging

I have internal server errors on my POST requests. How can I debug them ? Is it something to set up in php.ini ? THe file is really big and the word 'error' is met there many-many times.

Comment: Turn on your php errors.

Comment: Start from up to down and resolve with first error you encounter.

Comment: Check the above link. It has almost all in it what you need.

Comment: For me its not a PHP error, for some reasons its showing server error of 500.

Answer (score 83):

You can turn on your PHP errors with [`error_reporting`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php):

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'on');
```

Edit: It's possible that even after putting this, errors still don't show up. This can be caused if there is a fatal error in the script. From [PHP Runtime Configuration](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors):

> Although display_errors may be set at runtime (with ini_set()), it won't have any affect if the script has fatal errors. This is because the desired runtime action does not get executed.

You should set `display_errors = 1` in your `php.ini` file and *restart the server*.

Comment: And I will see errors in the browser console, right ? I think I dont see them now, though i managed my php.ini file.

Comment: You will see them in the browser itself, not in a console.

Comment: What platform/stack are you using? (Windows/Linux? Apache/IIS?)

Comment: I'm using linux + apache + firefox. No errors in the browser yet. Only error 500 in console.

Comment: Does a blank page also generate an error?: `<?php echo 'Hello'; `

Comment: No, blank page is fine, as fine as some non-blank pages.

Comment: Then you probably have an error in the script preventing runtime from even getting to these lines. You should update you `php.ini` file to include `display_errors = 1`, and restart the server. (Answer updated to show this.)

Comment: OOPS I forgot to restart the server, guys, reaally thank you, topic is closed. PS I never expected to recieve so fast flash help.

Comment: If you cannot modify php.ini, just add this in a .htaccess file: `php_flag display_errors 1`

Answer (score 30):

Try writing all the errors to a file.

```
error_reporting(-1); // reports all errors
ini_set("display_errors", "1"); // shows all errors
ini_set("log_errors", 1);
ini_set("error_log", "/tmp/php-error.log");
```

Something like that.

Comment: So I write this lines in my php scripts, at the top of them ?

Comment: @myadmins yes, before anything else. You could also set this in php.ini.