# AJAX Js Yii2 dropdown POST 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm using yii2 and a newbie in JavaScript and ajax.

I am getting this error:

> jquery.js:9175 POST http://localhost/istanagroup/web/purchase-order/basepricenet 500 (Internal Server Error)

here is the controller function

```html
public function actionBasepricenet(){
$id = $_POST['id'];
$model = MasterItem::find()->andFilterWhere(['id_master_item'=>$id])->one();
echo $model;
```

here is the js :

```js
$('#purchaseorderdetail-0-id_master_item').change(function(){
  var cat = $(this).val();
  $.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'http://localhost/istanagroup/web/purchase-order/basepricenet',
    data : {id:cat},
    dataType : 'text',
    success:function(res){
      console.log(res);
      $('#purchaseorderdetail-0-base_price').val(res);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: check PHP error log for detailed error explanation

Comment: Error is in PHP, check you are getting `id` in post by using `echo`, also check PHP error check this for info on error https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22170864/500-internal-server-error-how-to-debug

Comment: @GaneshGhalame i already checked the id, i got the id and i can echo it but the error come in $model.

Answer (score 0):

Folowing the Yii2 documentation,

> `andFilterWhere` adds an additional WHERE condition to the existing one but ignores empty operands.

In your case you do not have declared a `where()` condition. Furthermore, once the ID is always provided in the request, you could change the `andFilterWhere()` to a normal `where()`, as the following:

```html
public function actionBasepricenet(){
  if (isset($_POST['id'])){
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $model = MasterItem::find()->where(['id_master_item'=>$id])->one();
    var_dump($model);
  } else {
     // ID not received! Error!
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Claudio Busatto, i already got the id, but the error still in the $model.

Comment: What does it display when you call `var_dump($model->getErrors())` ?