# use inner join to filter products based on category

Tags: php, sql, inner-join, data-retrieval

The SQL query correctly selects the desired products from the database, however I can't get the php to output the data to the website. I need the data to be inside the HTML below as well. There is a problem inside the `if statement` block somewhere but I can't find it at all

SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE Product(
    Product_ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    Stock_Level int NOT NULL,
    Price int NOT NULL,
    Image blob NOT NULL,
    Admin_ID int NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (Product_ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (Admin_ID) REFERENCES Admins(Admin_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE Category(
    Category_ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Category varchar(15) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (Category_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE ProductLookup(
    ProductLookup_ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Product_ID int(100) NOT NULL,
    Category_ID int NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (ProductLookup_ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (Product_ID) REFERENCES Product(Product_ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (Category_ID) REFERENCES Category(Category_ID)
);
```

PHP:

```
   <?php
  //Connect to DB
  include_once 'DBConnection.php';

 //Query DB to find Meat Products based on category

  $sql = "SELECT p.Name, p.Price, p.Image FROM Product p INNER JOIN (ProductLookup pl) ON (p.Product_ID = pl.Product_ID) WHERE pl.Category_ID = 1;";

 $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
 $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
 if($resultCheck > 0){
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
      echo $row['Name'];
      echo $row['Price'];
      echo $row['Image'];
   }
} else{
  echo "Empty";
}
?>
```

HTML

```
<div class="panel-body">
                <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 product">
                <div class="product-price">£000</div>
                <a href="product.html">
                    <img src="#"/>
                </a>
                <div class="product-title">
                    Placeholder
                </div>
                <div class="product-add">
                    <?php
                    if(isset($_SESSION['id'])){
                     echo '<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Add To Basket</button>';
                    }else{
                        echo 'Please <a href="login.php">Log In to Purchase</a>';
                    }
                    ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Looks like you already have the filter in your query. Try to rephrase what you are going to achieve.

Comment: Just pass the ID in the URL and use that value instead of your current hard coded one.

Comment: I had the database with `Category_ID` in the `Product` table. However, for other purposes in the system I need each product to have multiple categories, hence the `ProductLookup` table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 problems:

The first is an error in your query. You're trying to get data from Products table but the name of the table is Product

Try this query:

```
SELECT p.Name, p.Price, p.Image
FROM Product p
INNER JOIN (ProductLookup pl) ON (p.Product_ID = pl.Product_ID)
WHERE pl.Category_ID = 1
```

And the second is an error at the line:

```
while($row = msqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
```

The function msqli_fetch_assoc is for Microsoft Database and not MySQL. You can use this:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
```

I made the following code and it worked well:

```
<?php

//Connect to DB
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'user', 'password', 'database');

//Query DB to find products
$sql = "SELECT Products.Name, Products.Price, Products.Image 
FROM Products 
INNER JOIN ProductLookup ON Products.Product_ID = ProductLookup.Product_ID 
WHERE ProductLookup.Category_ID = 1;";

$sql = "
SELECT p.Name, p.Price, p.Image
FROM Product p
INNER JOIN (ProductLookup pl) ON (p.Product_ID = pl.Product_ID)
WHERE pl.Category_ID = 1
";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);

?>


<div class="panel-body">
    <div class="row">

<?php

if ($resultCheck > 0) {

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { ?>

        <div class="col-md-4 product">
            <div class="product-price">
                £<?= $row['Price'] ?>
            </div>
            <a href="product.html">
                <img src="<?= $row['Image'] ?>"/>
            </a>
            <div class="product-title">
                <?= $row['Name'] ?>
            </div>
            <div class="product-add">
                <?= isset($_SESSION['id']) ? '<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Add To Basket</button>': 'Please <a href="login.php">Log In to Purchase</a>' ?>
            </div>
        </div>

    <?php }

} else {

    echo "<h2>There is no products avaliable</h2>";

}

?>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Gave it a go, it is still returning empty. I have data in my database with that category just to test

Comment: I ran the query inside my database and it works so thank you, however the php script returns empty so there is a problem inside the if statement block somewhere

Comment: Edited, check it out

Comment: `<?php
//Connect to DB
include_once 'DBConnection.php';

//Query DB to find Meat Products based on category

$sql = "SELECT p.Name, p.Price, p.Image FROM Product p INNER JOIN (ProductLookup pl) ON (p.Product_ID = pl.Product_ID) WHERE pl.Category_ID = 1;";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if($resultCheck > 0){
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
  echo $row['Name'];
  echo $row['Price'];
  echo $row['Image'];
 }
} else{
 echo "Empty";
}
?>`

Comment: That is my code as it stands, they are not being correctly echoed to the site

Comment: Tried your code, I am getting an error saying the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) now in my web inspector

Comment: This error can happen for a thousand of reasons. You can debug your code to find whats wrong. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22170864/500-internal-server-error-how-to-debug) is about how to debug the error. Hope you can find it.